# Discord.js v13 How to check if mute time is correctly specified?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

So I'm making a tempmute command in discord.js and I've almost finished it, there is just one more thing to foolproof and that is the mute time. See the proper command usage is something like: !tempmute @user 60m and that mutes them for 60 minutes (I'm using the npm ms package https://www.npmjs.com/package/ms). When I type the command correctly aka !tempmute @user 10m or any other amount of time supported by this package, it works like a charm. The problem is that if instead of giving time in a correct format or just put gibberish there it doesn't work and crashes my bot. How do I prevent that from happening?
Here's my code:

```js
const ms = require('ms');
const { Permissions, MessageActionRow, UserFlags } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'tempmute',
    description: "Temporarily mutes a user",
    execute(message, args)
    {
        const target = message.mentions.members.first();
        let muteRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "muted");
        if(message.member.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.MODERATE_MEMBERS))
        {
            if(target)
            {
                let memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);
                if(target.id == 'myBotsID')
                {
                    message.reply("I can't mute myself.")
                }
                else if(message.member == target)
                {
                    message.reply("You can't mute yourself!")
                }
                else if(memberTarget.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.MODERATE_MEMBERS))
                {
                    
                    message.channel.send(`<@${memberTarget.user.id}> has been muted for ${ms(ms(args[1]))}`);                
                }
                else 
                {
                    if(args[1])
                    {
                        memberTarget.roles.add(muteRole.id);
                        message.reply("<@" + memberTarget.user.id + ">" + "has been muted for " + ms(ms(args[1])))

                        setTimeout(function () {
                            memberTarget.roles.remove(muteRole.id);
                        }, ms(args[1]));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        message.reply("You have to specify the mute duration (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ms)")
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                message.reply("You have to mention a valid member of this server.")
            }
        }
        else
        {
            message.reply("You can't use that.")
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
C:\Users\Miki\Desktop\discord boty\jajco bot\node_modules\ms\index.js:34
  throw new Error(
  ^

Error: val is not a non-empty string or a valid number. val=undefined
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Miki\Desktop\discord boty\jajco bot\node_modules\ms\index.js:34:9)
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\Miki\Desktop\discord boty\jajco bot\commands\tempmute.js:34:99)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Miki\Desktop\discord boty\jajco bot\main.js:100:41)
    at Client.emit (node:events:520:28)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\Miki\Desktop\discord boty\jajco bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:26:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\Miki\Desktop\discord boty\jajco bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\Miki\Desktop\discord boty\jajco bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:351:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\Miki\Desktop\discord boty\jajco bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\Miki\Desktop\discord boty\jajco bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\Miki\Desktop\discord boty\jajco bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:199:18)
```

Comment: What is the error specifically?

Comment: Ah sorry forgot to mention it, I edited it in just now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
                        }, ms(args[1]));
```

In this lign here, `args[1]` is undefined (since the message doesn't contain a second argument) so `ms(undefined)` returns an error !

Try catching that error :

```js
if(!args[1]) return message.reply('time not given.')
try {
  let time = ms(args[1])
} catch (err) {
  message.reply("Can't transform into millisecond `"+args[1]+"`")
}
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to incorporate your suggested code into mine. I mean like where exactly do I put it?

Comment: nvm I figured it out, thanks so much for help!